# Balanced Accuracy on a multi class Confusion Matrix returning NA

Tags: r, data-analysis, r-caret, confusion-matrix

I'm working in a multi class confusion matrix using caret. I'm able to generate the CM without problems. But when I try to get the Balanced Accuracy, it returns NA.

```
             Reference
Prediction    dead onTreatment recovered
  dead           7           5         0
  onTreatment    4         200         6
  recovered      1           8        21

cm$byClass
                   Sensitivity Specificity Pos Pred Value Neg Pred Value Precision    Recall        F1 Prevalence
Class: dead          0.5833333   0.9791667      0.5833333      0.9791667 0.5833333 0.5833333 0.5833333 0.04761905
Class: onTreatment   0.9389671   0.7435897      0.9523810      0.6904762 0.9523810 0.9389671 0.9456265 0.84523810
Class: recovered     0.7777778   0.9600000      0.7000000      0.9729730 0.7000000 0.7777778 0.7368421 0.10714286
                   Detection Rate Detection Prevalence Balanced Accuracy
Class: dead            0.02777778           0.04761905         0.7812500
Class: onTreatment     0.79365079           0.83333333         0.8412784
Class: recovered       0.08333333           0.11904762         0.8688889

cm$byClass["Balanced Accuracy"]
[1] NA
```

Is it because I'm not setting a positive factor? (I think it doesn't make sense on my case)

Should I calculate it manually? (Using the Mean of all classes)

Comment: `cm$byClass[["Balanced Accuracy"]]`

Comment: It returns an error: Error in cm$byClass[["Balanced Accuracy"]] : subscript out of bounds

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why it doesn't work so I calculated it manually by getting the mean of all classes sensitivity.

```
mean(cm$byClass[,"Sensitivity"])
[1] 0.7809598
```

Ty.